# VSCode plugin doesn't read the parameters in settings.json until I restart the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a plugin for VSCode.

The parameters used are read from the `settings.json` file and can be modified by the user on the `extension settings` page.

The line of code used to read a parameter from `settings.json` is:

```js
const value = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(configKey).get('parameterName');
```

When I start the plugin the parameters are read correctly, but if I change them in the `extension settings` page the changes are not recognized. However, if I close the editor and restart it, the modified parameters are finally recognized and used.

Is this a normal behavior for a plugin or is there a system that I don't know about to make the plugin immediately recognize parameter changes as soon as they are set by the user?

Comment: you have to add a hook to listen to changed settings and reload the settings if it applies to your settings

Comment: @rioV8 Can you point me to a link where I can read something in detail about this technique?

Comment: How many `On(Did)Change` methods are to be found on the API page, one of them you need to use

Comment: do you read the setting only in `activate` or each time when needed

Comment: what is `config.json`?

Comment: are you reading the configuration value every time you want to use it? or are you reading it on startup and caching the value? usually people do the former.

Comment: As rioV8 says you have to listen, via `onDidChangeConfiguration()` for when the user changes a setting you are interested in.  And then react accordingly.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the solution on my own by reading the VSCode API documentation and the code written for the extensions of many software houses.

There is no direct and clean way to intercept changes made to configuration parameters and consequently make them automatically active.

The only way to activate the new configuration parameter values ​​is to restart VSCode or call the `Reload window` command:

1. `F1` or `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Shift+Command+P`;
2. type `reload window`;
3. choose `Developer: Reload Window`;

If, however, you are developing a new extension for VSCode, remember to add a paragraph to the `README.md` file in which you explain to the user the procedure I have just written.

Comment: this is an incorrect answer, by not putting in a bit of effort and searching the API and reading the correct extensions you are no step closer to a working solution then at the time of the question. In my extensions you don't need to restart VSC when you change an extension, how do you think VSC works when you change the theme

Comment: You asked "is there a system that I don't know about to make the plugin immediately recognize parameter changes as soon as they are set by the user?"  And `onDidChangeConfiguration()` is precisely that system.  Rarely is that not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration` should give you the current value of the setting at the time that you call it. Once you read the value out into a variable, that variable isn't going to magically update when the setting changes. You'd need to read the setting value out again by calling `getConfiguration` again. You can listen for configuration changes with `onDidChangeConfiguration`, but I've seen a fair share of extensions that don't bother caching configuration values, and just read the value out every time they're going to use it to perform some action. Then you don't need to bother listening for changes